# FAIL - Application at context path /my_app could not be started

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5

I am facing this error on tomcat. This is the link to web.xml: [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5q4t0oyeecnowf/web.xml). There were other posts as well related to other posts but i think i am doing something wrong in my web.xml. Need help.
Thanks in advance ! Here is the manager log file

> Jun 21, 2014 12:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 12:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 12:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:35:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:36:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:40:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:40:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:40:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:40:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:41:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:41:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:41:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:41:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:49:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 1:49:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:04:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:06:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:06:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:40:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:40:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:40:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:40:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: stop: Stopping web application at '/'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: stop: Stopping web application at '/tomcat-docs'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:41:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:43:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:43:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:44:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:46:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:46:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:55:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:55:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:55:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:55:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:55:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: stop: Stopping web application at '/'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:56:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:57:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app\WB-INF' from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 2:57:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:03:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:03:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:48:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:48:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:48:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 3:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 4:29:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 4:29:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 4:29:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 4:30:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 4:30:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 7:41:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 7:41:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
>   Jun 21, 2014 7:41:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
>   Jun 21, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/my_app'
>   Jun 21, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'

Comment: This is nowhere near enough detail to diagnose the problem. That error message is basically "something went wrong", there should be a stack trace or similar further back in one of your log files telling you what the actual underlying error was.

Comment: are you talking about log files placed at "tomcat/logs" ? should i paste details of log files here ? i have to submit my project by tomorrow need quick response. Thanks

Comment: You should look through those log files and see if any of them tell you what actually went wrong. The smoking gun could be in any of the log files but my rule of thumb is that it's often the _last_ layer of "caused by" in the _earliest_ exception stack trace you can find (within the time window of this particular tomcat run, of course). You may find this error message is enough to diagnose the problem yourself, but if not then edit the question to include the stack trace and someone will probably be able to help.

Comment: I have edit my question and paste manager log file details, what is  problem in it ?

Comment: There's no error message in there, just an activity log of what the manager has been doing. Are there no exception stack traces in any of the other log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled JSP files will become servlets at runtime automatically. You don't have to map them in your web.xml. You should read some [JSP tutorials](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jsp+tutorial) before going on. By the way, Servlet API 2.4 is really outdated.

**Updated**

To run JSP files you only need to put them into your web apps folder and call them by adding their name to your url, i.e. 'yourdomain.com/appName/jspFileName.jsp'. There already is a JSP servlet defined in your Tomcats conf/web.xml. You dont have to change anything there.

Comment: What should i write in web.xml ? i have not enough time to go through the tutorials , i have to submit it ASAP, kindly help me out ! Thanks !